# Simple ridge regression task

Tags: regression, machine-learning, optimization, linear, ridge-regression

Given is one single datapoint $\vec{x}$, which contains the same feature twice, hence $\vec{x} = (x,x)$ and a label y. We have to add the regularization term $\lambda*||\vec{\beta}||^2$, $\lambda > 0$ to the regular linear regression problem,  solve this problem, as well as explain what relationship the components of the solution $\vec{\beta^*}$ satisfy. I would use the following equation to solve the problem by hand:
$(X^TX)*\vec{\beta} - \lambda*\vec{\beta}= X^Ty$, specifically for our problem:

$\begin{bmatrix} x^2 & x^2\\ x^2& x^2\end{bmatrix} *\begin{bmatrix}\beta_1 \\ \beta_2 \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}\lambda\beta_1 \\ \lambda\beta_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}xy \\ xy \end{bmatrix} $

Is this correct so far? I know for ridge regression, the closed form solution always exist (the added regularization allows for invertibility), but I am not sure what I can conclude for the solution and the components in this particular case.

Comment: Your approach is correct so far but you can still simplify the solution to 
\begin{align*}
\beta&=(X^TX-\lambda I)^{-1}X^Ty\\
     &= \pmatrix{x^2-\lambda & x^2\\ x^2 & x^2 -\lambda}^{-1}\pmatrix{x\\x}y\\
     &= \pmatrix{(\frac{x(x^2-\lambda)}{\lambda^2-2\lambda x^2} -\frac{x^3}{\lambda^2-2\lambda x^2})y\\ (\frac{x(x^2-\lambda)}{\lambda^2-2\lambda x^2} -\frac{x^3}{\lambda^2-2\lambda x^2})y}\\
   &=\pmatrix{-\frac{x}{\lambda-2x^2}y \\-\frac{x}{\lambda-2x^2}y  }
\end{align*}

Comment: Now solve the system. What do you get?

Comment: Thanks! I just assumed that for this exercise we don't know yet that the closed form solution can be used for ridge even though $(X^TX)^-1$ is not invertible:) Anyway, I see that obviously the $\beta$s are equal - but that seems trivial - so what exactly do they want to know if they ask for the relationships between the betas?

Comment: thats a good question. don't know what to get from this toyexample besides showing that the inverse exists indeed in this special case...maybe: suppose $\lambda \to 0$ and $y=\beta_1 x + \beta_2 x = x (\beta_1+\beta_2)$ then it can be immediately seen that the ridge estimator for $\beta_j$ is just $(\beta_1+\beta_2)/2$ for each of the "two" parameters.

Comment: How did you get $(X^TX)\vec\beta - \lambda\vec\beta = X^Ty$? In particular, I'm wondering about the negative sign in front of $\lambda$.

Comment: oops brent is right :) the sign is wrong. unfortunately i can not edit my former comment anymore.  the correct solution should be $\beta_j = \frac{x}{\lambda + 2x^2}y$, $j=1,2$.

Comment: Just by derivation of $||Y-X\beta||+\lambda||\beta||^2$, corrected now @MatthewGunn you mean solving for y? chRrr: yes we have shown previously (with the help of Matthew) that there is no closed form solution without regularization

Comment: @TestGuest You are maximizing over $\beta_1, \beta_2$. Solve for $\boldsymbol{\beta}$. And the proper statement would be there is no *unique* closed form solution to this problem without regularization; indeed there are an infinite number of solutions without regularization.

Comment: ...it is already solved for $\beta$...by chRrr? I see, thanks!